# Push notification no webview - Android / iOS

Tags: android, webview, push-notification, android-webview, firebase-cloud-messaging

Estou com um app rodando um webview. Ele é um sistema na web e o webview com o app.

No sistema, tem determinadas ações que o sistema envia push notification para o usuário.

Fiz a integração com o firebase cloud messaging Javascript. Mas ele nao funciona no webview, somente acessando diretamente pelo browser.

Pelo que estava pesquisando, eu teria que configurar a parte de javascript, para web, e no webview configurar de novo para funcionar no webview, mas meu conhecimento de Java é bem pouco, e uso a base de dados na web pra enviar os push.

Alguém sabe se tem como eu fazer essa integração via Javascript e funcionar tanto no browser quanto no webview?

Comment: Creio que o problema disto é que o webView não poderia ser destruído, por exemplo se fechar o app ou então o tempo ocioso finalizar ele (gerenciamento de consumo do celular faz isto por questão de bateria e performance) quando colocado em background por muito tempo ou abre um outro app pesado ou seja enquanto o seu app estiver aberto o webView vai conseguir notificar, se fechado não. O ideal seria criar um Task (serviço em background) que leria um formato json e enviaria pushs, totalmente independente do webView.

Answer (score 1):

O javaScript não é bem embarcado em um App no iOS.
O que você pode fazer é ir no seu método que recebe o Push Notification (se não tiver, basta implementar no AppDelegate, pois deveria ter).

E então, no lugar de WebView, tente usar o [CSafariWebKit](https://github.com/dmandarino/CSafariWebKit). A Apple recomende que não engane seu usuário com uso de webview, se o conteúdo é web. A excessão é se precisar de algo mais customizado e a tela for inteiramente do seu app.

No seu arquivo

```
import CSafariWebKit
```

E no lugar que quiser chamar a WebView

```
let vc = SafariViewController(url: url, barTintColor: nil, tintColor: nil)
vc.presentSafari(fromViewController: self, whenDidFinish: nil)
```

Use as cores do seu app para uma melhor experiência.